# Display a specific row table based on row content

Tags: javascript, jquery

so i need to display some specific rows of my table based on the row content with JS

this is the example : 
[image]

I need to display the `tr` where the `td` has an element `i` class `fa fa-heart`
Is it possible ?

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but **you'll need a much more specific question than that**, and **you'll need to show that you've made a reasonable attempt to solve this on your own**. I imagine that the latter would lead you to the former. Please take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the meantime.

Comment: Also always post actual code when asking a question and never a picture of code - if you cannot be bothered to recreate the code for us, then why should anyone be bothered to help you - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: I couldn't upload the code because I'm working with pug .js (no HTML) and the code HTML, in this case, explains more the question, so that's why i made a screenshot! thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

To display the `className` of the `i` element in the `td` :

```
$('#myTable tr:eq(1) td:eq(1)')[0].children[0].className
```

For checking if it is the right value you need to loop through all the table elements